# Draw rectangle over uploaded image

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Once I upload an image I make 2 clicks over it. That's how (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) are obtained. Given these 4 numbers I waanna draw a rectangle over the image by means for example of P5.js. Then I should say rect(x1,y1,x2,y2) but this never happens. How can I deal with this problem (maybe not by P5)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Vue Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="isHidden = false">Load img</button>
  <img onclick="showCoords(event)" v-if="!isHidden" v-bind:src="src[z]"></img>
</div>

  <script>

var test = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    src: ["cat.jpg", "dog.jpg"],
    z: Math.round(Math.random()),
    isHidden: true,
  }
})

var k=0;
var koors = [];
var flag = false;
function showCoords(event) {
  if (k===0){
    koors[0] = event.clientX;
    koors[1] = event.clientY;
    k+=1;
  } else if (k===1){
    flag = true;
    koors[2] = event.clientX;
    koors[3] = event.clientY;
  }
if ((koors[3] != 0) && (flag)){
  console.log(koors)
}
}
//p5
function setup(){
}
function draw(){
  console.log(koors[0],koors[1],koors[2],koors[3]);
  rect(koors[0],koors[1],koors[2],koors[3])
}


  </script>

  <script src="p5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

P5 needs a canvas for rendering. If you don't initialize one, it creates it himself (and you are in trouble).
Also, P5 is powerful library, it has tools for events, image processing etc. For current example I wouldn't use any other library (vue).

I created canvas on top of the image (css) and rest is playing with P5.

```js
var test = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    src: [ "https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg"],
    z: Math.round(Math.random()),
    isHidden: false,
  }
})

var recStart;
var coords = {};

/*******************************************************************
* P5 setup 
* run once, use for initialisation.
*
* Create a canvas, change dimensions to 
* something meaningful(like image dim)
********************************************************************/
function setup(){
  var canvas = createCanvas(480, 320);
  canvas.parent('app');
}

/*******************************************************************
* P5 draw
* endless loop.
* 
* Lets redraw rectangle until second click. 
********************************************************************/
function draw(){
 if(recStart)
  drawRect();
}

/*******************************************************************
* drawRect
* 
* Draw a rectangle. mouseX and mouseY are P5 variables
* holding mouse current position.
********************************************************************/
function drawRect(){
 clear();
 noFill();
 stroke('red');
 rect(coords.x, coords.y, mouseX-coords.x, mouseY-coords.y);
}

/*******************************************************************
* P5 mouseClicked
* 
* P5 event. Again,  mouseX and mouseY are used. 
********************************************************************/
mouseClicked = function() {
    if (mouseButton === LEFT) {
  if(!recStart){   // start rectangle, give initial coords
   coords.x = mouseX;
   coords.y = mouseY;
   recStart = true; // draw() starts to draw
  } else {
   recStart = false; // stop draw()
   drawRect();   // draw final rectangle
   coords = {};  // clear coords
  }
    }
};
```

```css
 canvas {
  width: 500px;
  height:500px;
  z-index: 2;
  border:1px solid;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
 }
 img {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <img id="pilt" v-if="!isHidden" v-bind:src="src[z]"></img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't call `draw` anywhere. You may also consider draw the image into a canvas and than draw rect in this canvas. Checking if `koors[3] != 0` is really risky as user may click at 0th pixel.